# Drop or truncate sub-partitions in Greenplum

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

How to drop or truncate sub-partitions in Greenplum? I am unable to find any syntax that can drop a sub-partition (for a specific partition specifically) from a table. Thanks.

Comment: be more specific ?? show sample table etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with syntax:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER PARTITION partition_name TRUNCATE PARTITION subpartition_name;`

I found it in official docs but it's not easy to deduce.

See: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4350/ref_guide/sql_commands/ALTER_TABLE.html